# Title Subtitle order on Single Page Applications with no regard for SEO

Tags: web-app

Though similar to [App title or page title in the title bar of an app?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/98250/app-title-or-page-title-in-the-title-bar-of-an-app) this is for a web application.  That is **not SEO oriented** and it is a **Single Page Application**

Should I use

```
<title>[app name] - [app page]</title>
```

Or

```
<title>[app page] - [app name]</title>
```

Personally I like to put the page first because I don't have to look too far into the title bar to see the title, it's much like most of the Windows apps from Microsoft where they put the title of the application at the end.

I don't care much about SEO for this question and the `document.title` would be dynamically set via JavaScript anyway.  For SEO if it mattered, I would put the

```
<title>[app name]</title>
```

Since it is a single page application.

Only problem I can think of is bookmarking.  When people bookmark and they just scan through the list, it is usually with the title of the application they look for.  However, I haven't seen any responses to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299057/can-i-override-the-title-of-a-bookmark-for-a-web-page so that would be a slight concern.  I guess one can expect the user to change the title or move to a folder as they see fit.

Comment: Minor exception, this is not for SEO but for usability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Put the most useful information first

In this case it is the name of the page.  As the world transitions almost exclusively to smaller devices every character of text on the screen is at a premium.  The user only needs to know where they are in the application once they launch it.  Use your second option.

## Having unique characters at the beginning of a string is helpful to people using a screen reader

I recently had the opportunity to watch a blind user navigate our website using a screen reader.  He had the ability to listen to less than a second of sound while jumping around the different browser menu items.

I felt his pain as he got to a list of links on our site where he had to listen for 3 or 4 whole seconds to get to the distinguishable word in every menu item.

This is true of bookmarks in your app as well so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: I am curious what you mean by `Having unique characters`?  Are you saying put some emojis and such to represent the page/

Comment: Oh no.  I only meant don't have a list of items where the first characters in the string are the same.  For example, `Build baseline environment for BETA`, `Build baseline environment for Production`, etc.